# Convolutional layer error using tf.agents with GPU activated

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I running DQN training tutorial with tf.agents(https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial), and I am trying to change the model they use with just dense layers to have some convolutional ones on top[image]

When I run this on colab without GPU its all fine, but when I connect to GPU I get this error.[image]

Is it because conv layers are not available yet with GPU with tf.agents or are there some dependencies extra that I have to install to be able to do this?

Comment: This means it cannot find cuDNN, it should be in your library path.

Comment: But doesn't colab have cuDNN instaled by default?

Comment: "Cannot find" is not the same as "not installed", maybe it expects different versions, etc.